# How to convert a C ++ code to the math notation in Latex

Tags: math-mode

I have a question about whether I'm doing it right. I have a C ++ code that checks if a certain item is in the radius of another item, whenever a counter is incremented. This counter is used for a split in the sequence. C ++ code below for illustration.

```cpp
int s = 0;
int r=200;
for( int i = 0; i<A.size();++i){
   for( int j = 0; j<P.size();++j){
      if( fRadius(r,P[j],A[i] ) != OUTSIDE)
         ++s;
   }
}
float f = 1000.0/s;
```

In Latex I wrote as follows:

```latex
fCountRadius(A,P) = \frac{1000}{\sum_{m=1}^{size(A)} \  1 \ \forall \ fRadius(r,A_m,\{ P_1,P_2,\dots, P_{size(P)} \}) \neq OUTSIDE}
```

It is clear? Is math correct? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: you probably should use `\operatorname{fCountRadius}` etc. Otherwise, the letters are italic, but only variables should be italic according to most typesetting rules for equations. Otherwise one could not distinguish between the name `fCountRadius` and the product `f*C*o*u*...*i*u*s`. The operatorname sets the letters upright. The same should be done for `OUTSIDE` due to the same reasons.

Comment: it's hard to show an imperative algorithm as traditional math layout, you could show the original C++ using listings or minted to syntax colour them, or use one of the pseudocode packages (algorith2e, algorithmx, ...) to lay it out as pseudocode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would translate this to the double summation of an indicator function.  So perhaps something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
% To make the output fit in the allowed size for TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareRobustCommand\arr[1]{\symbf{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fRadius{\operatorname{fRadius}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\OUTSIDE{\mathop{\text{\textsc{outside}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\ICr{I_{C_r}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
             r &= 200 \\
    \ICr(x, y) &= \begin{cases}
                    0 &\text{ if } \fRadius (r, x, y)
                      \text{ is } \OUTSIDE \\
                    1 &\text{ otherwise}
                  \end{cases} \\
             s &= \sum_{a \in \arr{A}} \sum_{p \in \arr{P}} \ICr(p, a) \\
             f &= \frac{1000}{s}
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Proposed definitions]

Most C++ compilers refactor your source in the exact same way, as a step in the optimization process, when they transform to Static Single Assignment.  In that context, those new functions are called phi functions, and if you need a generic naming scheme for them, you might go with *ϕ*₁ (`$\phi_1$`), etc.

If you find that description clear, you might even make your original program look a little more like it. [All modern compilers on GodBolt are able to vectorize this code,](https://godbolt.org/z/ZLmVyW) as well as the code you wrote.

```c++
#include <vector>

using Collection = std::vector<int>;

static inline bool fRadius( const int r, const int p, const int a )
{
  return r*r >= p*p + a*a;
}

static inline int indicator_C_r ( const int p, const int a )
{
  constexpr int r = 200;
  return fRadius( r, p, a ) ? 1 : 0;
}

double fCountRadius( const Collection& A, const Collection& P )
{
  int s = 0;

  for ( const auto a : A )
    for ( const auto p : P )
      s += indicator_C_r( p, a );

  return 1000.0 / s;
}
```

There are of course many alternatives.  One terse one in common notation is: defining the magnitude ‖(p,a)‖ of a coordinate pair, defining the set (or bag, if there can be duplicates) of points within the circle by specification, and taking its cardinality.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \left\lvert \left\{
     (p, a) \in P \times A
     : \lVert (p, a) \rVert \leq r
   \right\}\right\rvert
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Specification]

Comment: Thanks for help!! Your explanation is very good!!!